# How to replay conversation through nodeJs using messagebird WhatsApp Business API?

Tags: messagebird

How to test?

get started from this url: https://developers.messagebird.com/docs/whatsapp/getting-started/

var messagebird = require('messagebird')();

my code

```
messagebird.conversations.reply(data.id, {
      'type': 'image',
      'content': {
        'image': {
          'url': 'https://api.faridblaster.my/test',
          'caption': 'Bocaahhh3332'
        }
      }
    }, function (err, response) {
      if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
      }
    });
```

the result show me

[image]

Expected Output should be

**status: 'delivered',**

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the provided [examples](https://developers.messagebird.com/api/conversations/#the-message-object), this is the expected status right after you are sending the message.

If you'd like to monitor the status changes for the message, you will have to register a webhook for the message.updated events and you'll get your updates in the reportURL (details [here](https://support.messagebird.com/hc/en-us/articles/360003987917-How-do-I-receive-WhatsApp-messages-statuses-))